# How can I invalidateQueries, react-query, within a redux-toolkit reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-query

As its probably obvious, I am trying to have a couple of APIs, used within the redux-toolkit reducer all invalidate my queries, react-query. BUT, I can't get it to work because of not being able to use "hooks" within the reducer. Instead of tracking down all the api calls.. and then invalidating "n" number of times, I figure to just do something like... but of course, not working. Anyone have ingenius way of invaliding queries from "n" number of api calls?

```
  .addMatcher(
    (action): action is AnyAction =>
      [
        asyncActions.someAction1.fulfilled,
        asyncActions.someAction2.fulfilled,
        asyncActions.someAction3.fulfilled,
        asyncActions.someAction4.fulfilled,
      ].some(actionCreator => actionCreator.match(action)),
    (state, action: AnyAction) => {

      // INVALIDATE MY QUERIES HERE
    }
  )
```

NOTE: I know redux-toolkit has it's own query. But I have a fast project and don't have time to learn it and also, by upgrading my toolkit, it creates massive amounts of TS errors (I guess a lot TS changes with later versions)...

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to trigger any side effect in a Redux Reducer, ever. You will need to find another place to do something like this - if you want to tie it to the Redux action being dispatched, you could look into the [listener middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware).